# $L_{x}f=f$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ implies $f=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ if $ L_{x}f=f$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ then $f=0$.
That is 'if for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $ f(y-x)=f(y)$ for almost every $y \in \mathbb{R}$  (we take lebesgue measure) then $f$ is zero almost everywhere'

Is this a true statement? If true what is the proof ? I couldn't figure out a proof, that is why I put it here.

Comment: How about Fourier transform?

Comment: @r9m That seems promising, only concern with it would be that Fourier Transform is defined via a limiting process on $\mathbb{L}^2$ and it is not clear to me that you can find an approximation $f_n$ of $f$ by Schwartz functions such that $L_xf_n = f_n$ for all $x$.

Comment: @rubikscube09 All the density of Schwarz space in $L^2$ etc are used to define (extend) the Fourier transform (FT) on the space. The end result being FT is an isometry in $L^2$. All properties that are satisfied by FT on Schwarz space naturally carries over to $L^2$ by density. For example here we just apply FT on both sides on $f(y - x) = f(y)$ to see that $e^{2\pi i x\xi}\hat{f}(\xi) = \hat{f}(\xi)$, for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Doesn't the hypothesis imply $\int_{[k,k+1]}|f|^2$ is independent of $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and since these sum to $\lVert f\rVert_2$, they must be $0$, so $|f|^2=0$  and $f=0$?

Comment: @Thorgott I think you are right this works. I think this works even if $f∈L^{p}(\mathbb{R}).0<p<\infty$